# I have to answer the question R studio

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Two computer factories assemblies notebooks from the same finished parts using different technologies. The measured assembly-times in factory A and B are the following

```
A: 34.5 34.2  35  35.1  36  35.2  35.7  34.8  34.9  34.4
B: 35   34.2  36  35    34  34.2  34.2  34.5  34.4
```

Is the assembly technology in factory B faster? 
Formulate the hypotheses and after performing the corresponding tests interpret their results (use alpha=0.05 and suppose that both samples are normally distributed)!
could any one help me, thank you

Comment: This is a homework/exam type problem and requires the self study tag.

Comment: I will give you some issues to think about and show you some procedures in R to get you started. But you are on your own to give an explicit answer to this question. Maybe you can edit comments on some of the issues into your Question.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. suppose that both samples are normally distributed and use alpha=0.05 as the chance of rejecting the null hypothesis when it is true.

The null hypothesis was that the two means are not significantly different
According to t-test result, we accept the null hypothesis because the t value (t = 1.3423) which is less than our critical value ( our critical value is 2.1).  Am I right? Or I have use another test

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion you should begin by asking yourself some questions other than how to do
a test for this in R studio. Here are some questions to consider before
you start:

(a) What null hypothesis and alternative are involved in the test?
(b) What test procedure should you perform, and why?
(c) How do you plot the data so you can get an idea what is going on?
(d) What is the formula for the test statistic?
(e) What is the point of assuming data to be normal? How can you check this?
(f) What R code should you use?

Here are some results from R. I will let you figure out answers to required
items among (a)-(f) and how to get results using R Studio.

```
A = c(34.5, 34.2, 35, 35.1, 36, 35.2, 35.7, 34.8, 34.9, 34.4) 
summary(A)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  34.20   34.58   34.95   34.98   35.17   36.00 
sd(A)
[1] 0.5613476
length(A)
[1] 10

B = c(35, 34.2, 36, 35, 34, 34.2, 34.2, 34.5, 34.4)
summary(B)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  34.00   34.20   34.40   34.61   35.00   36.00 
sd(B)
[1] 0.6293736
length(B)
[1] 9
```

Because the sample mean $\bar X_A = 34.98 > \bar X_B = 34.61$ (by just a little)
it seems that Factory B is a little faster than Factory A, but maybe not by enough to be deemed statistically significant.

```
boxplot(A, B, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

```
        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  B
W = 0.83208, p-value = 0.04712
```

Output from one procedure in R for testing $H_0: \mu_A = \mu_B$ against $H_1: \mu_A > \mu_B$ is shown below:

```
        Two Sample t-test

data:  A and B
t = 1.3509, df = 17, p-value = 0.09722
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is greater than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.106156       Inf
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 34.98000  34.61111
```

Does this test show reason to reject $H_0?$  Why or why not?
What procedure did I use? What other procedure might I have used?